lora finetuning : training loss decrease sharply between two epochs, decrease slowly during one epoch


As in the pictures, validation loss decreases normaly, training loss during one epoch is also decrease, but slowly. Why training loss decreases sharply between 2 epochs? How should I change parameters to map this gap?
I tried increasing batch_size, it works. But loss is even higher, precision and recall are worse. I made learning_rate smaller, but it dosen't work. Someone says the model saw all data in epoch 1, so in epoch 2, it memorized the data, but I tried to decrease max_samples, loss is even higher. Is this big gap a problem? If yes, what parameter should I change?

The sharp decrease is due to the fact that the model is now seeing repeat data points that it has already seen, and so is likely overfitting to some degree.
It is not necessarily a problem as long as you continue measuring against some held-out validation set and ensure that your loss is decreasing as well.
